# How to check how much money in the user account in a mobile network?

Tags: android

I have my Android app and I want to know information about user network account. 
So, how to check how much money in the user account in a mobile network from my android app?
Thank you for help and your time!

Comment: Without a very good explanation of why, this sounds quite suspicious.

Comment: I do not understand why the suspect. Information about something does not mean access to it.
However I need it in order to provide users with information why he can not download Web pages and so on.

Comment: It sounds suspicious because such information could be used by a malicious app to decide if it's worth trying to steal that balance by automatically requesting lots of pay-per-use services.  Are these web pages the user must purchase from you via carrier billing?  Or pay-per-byte service plans?  At any rate, this would require a carrier specific API - and not a USSD based one as android doesn't provide an API for apps to access that yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you would need a Network API for that.
Don't believe this info is given out freely on Android or any other mobile device.